# Spring Data MongoTemplate exceptions during save

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, exception

I have the following code to perform a save to Mongo from my Java application using Spring data.
How do I handle exceptions that may happen during this save? This DAO method of mine is called from a ServiceImpl class.

```
public void saveDraftNote(Note draftNote) {
    try {
        mongoTemplate.save(draftNote);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Error handling
    }
}
```

Should I catch exception? Or catch specific exceptions? 
How can I pass this to my ServiceImpl? Can I wrap the DAO exceptiosn into a custom ServiceException to handle in my ServiceImpl?

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, and I ended up digging into the MongoTemplate code. Bottom line, the methods can throw various subclasses of RunTimeException. From what I saw, there is no purpose in trying to determine which ones. My preferred pattern is to catch Exception, log the exception, and throw a generic subclass of RuntimeException.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to handle exception here.if you are concern about is your records saved successfully or not use `WriteResult`

In your case

```
public void saveDraftNote(Note draftNote) {

       WriteResult result = mongoTemplate.save(draftNote);

}
```

Return result to your business layer you can easily validate using

```
if (reult.getN() != 1)
            //throw your exception...
```

Comment: Not sure I agree but I need to do some more digging before I suggest an answer. Mouse over the save() method and you will see: "Method 'save()' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception". What I want to find is what sort of exception(s) we might encounter.